# Django manage.py migrate > NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I use Django for web development. When i make some changes in models then i run "Python manage.py makemigrations" and "python manage.py migrate".  But at migrate code running i got some errors as follows:

```
> python manage.py makemigrations 
No changes detected
```

```
> python manage.py migrate        
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, home, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying home.0020_image_desc_image_propertytype...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 90, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__home_image.desc


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\genio\OneDrive\Documents\HamroKothaProject\hello\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\genio\OneDrive\Documents\HamroKothaProject\hello\manage.py", line 18, in main    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 108, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 394, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 333, in _remake_table
    self.execute(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 104, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 81, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 90, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\genio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__home_image.desc
```

Following is my home.model:

from django.db import models

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=None)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    phone = models.TextField(max_length=10, default=None)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=None)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried to migrate all migrations but it cant happen. I want to fix that issue. So please anybody help me for that issue.

Comment: Please add `home` model definition to your question.

Comment: Try to delete last 2 migrations file and try again

Answer (score 0):

Without viewing the models and migrations it would be hard to figure it out, but from the error logs that you have shared, it does say `NOT NULL constraint failed`

This implies that in the new migration, there probably is a new field you have added which is required, cannot be NULL, and has no default value to it.

Probable fix could be to add a default value to the field in that model

From the logs the model appears to be `Home`, and the field appears to be `Image Desc`